# How to Get coordinates of detected area in opencv using python

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates

I have been able to successfully detect an object(face and eye) using haar cascade classifier in python using opencv. When the object is detected, a rectangle is shown around the object. I want to get coordinates of mid point of the two eyes. and want to store them in a array. Can any one help me? how can i do this. any guide

Comment: Why not just use center of rectangles?

Comment: I need the point which is in between the two eyes. Not the centre of the rectangle

Comment: Then get the center of the two rectangles and average that to get the mid-point between the two boxes which will be between the two eyes.

Answer (score 0):

So you already detected the eye? You also have a bounding box around the eye?
So your question comes down to calculatiing the distance between 2 bounding boxes and then dividing it by 2?
Or do I misunderstand?
If you need exact the center between the two eyes a good way to go about that would be to take the center of the 2 boxes bounding the 2 eyes.
Calculate the distance between those two points and divide it by 2.

If you're willing to post your code I'm willing to help more with writing code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the coordinates for the bounding boxes of both eyes.
Something like X1:X2 Y1:Y2 for both boxes.
You just have to find the center of these boxes: (X2-X1)/2+X1 and (Y2-Y1)/2+Y1
You'll get two XY coordinates from this, basically just do the above again with these coordinates, and you'll get the center point